# iOS URLCache caching when it shouldn't (IMHO)

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlsession, nsurlcache

Does anyone know why this request is being cached?

- I'm using an unmodified `.default` `URLSessionConfiguration`.
- The response headers are:

(from Charles, confirmed from debugging the response in the data tasks's completion block)

```
{
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Content-Length" = 1480;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Mon, 22 May 2017 19:14:13 GMT";
    Etag = "\"42bebc5fb88323b8cd145ed85ea7a018\"";
    "Last-Modified" = "Mon, 22 May 2017 14:54:38 GMT";
    Server = AmazonS3;
    "x-amz-id-2" = "abcdefghijklmn";
    "x-amz-request-id" = 1A2B3C4D5E;
}
```

- I'm verifying that the request is cached using Charles proxy - the first request appears, but subsequent requests don't.
- Using `.ephemeral` session configuration, or setting a custom url cache with 0 for memory and disk size shows all the requests in Charles, so I know Charles is a valid test.

I've always assumed that without cache headers a response won't be cached :|

Any ideas anyone?

---

EDIT: Here's the request I'm making

```
po task.originalRequest
▿ Optional<URLRequest>
  ▿ some : http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/path/configuration.json
    ▿ url : Optional<URL>
      ▿ some : http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/path/configuration.json
    - cachePolicy : 0
    - timeoutInterval : 60.0
    - mainDocumentURL : nil
    - networkServiceType : __ObjC.NSURLRequest.NetworkServiceType
    - allowsCellularAccess : true
    ▿ httpMethod : Optional<String>
      - some : "GET"
    - allHTTPHeaderFields : nil
    - httpBody : nil
    - httpBodyStream : nil
    - httpShouldHandleCookies : true
    - httpShouldUsePipelining : false
```

Comment: What does the request look like?

Comment: @Koen. It's just a GET for a url pointing to an S3 bucket - no custom headers etc. Nothing interesting at all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've always assumed that without cache headers a response won't be cached :|

That's not how it works, it WILL cache responses even without `Cache-Control` or `Expires` headers, if [all other criteria met](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiondatadelegate/1411612-urlsession?language=objc). However, it will use heuristics for determining cached response freshness, as exact expiration time was not provided in response headers. `NSURLCache` is implemented according to section 13 of [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13) and this behavior is stated there.

For more information you can check the following articles:

- [A Primer In Http–caching And Its–native Support–by–ios](http://qnoid.com/2016/04/10/A-primer-in-HTTP-caching-and-its-native-support-by-iOS.html)
- [Image Caching](https://kean.github.io/blog/image-caching)